# How to perform JSON object updates using jq commandline utility

Tags: javascript, json, shell, jq

I have a JSON object as follows

> {"Sample" : [{        "key": "KeyName",       "values": [             [1025409600000,
>   10],          [1028088000000, -6.3382185140371]
>            ] }]}

Using javascript I can modify any values as follows

```
data.Sample[0].values.push([1028088000000,0]);
```

How to perform the similar operation using jq commandline json processor? So the JSON object becomes

> {"Sample" : [{ "key": "KeyName", "values": [ [1025409600000, 10],
>   [1028088000000, 0] ] }]}

Thank you.

Comment: so what is the expected output? 1028088000000 replaced by 0?

Comment: Thanks for your response. So the JSON obj becomes 

{"Sample" : [{ "key": "KeyName", "values": [ [1025409600000, 10], [1028088000000, 0] ] }]}

Answer (score 2):

As it stands there is a bug in the question, as Javascript's Array.push appends to an array.

The jq equivalent of the given expression:

```
data.Sample[0].values.push([1028088000000,0]);
```

would be:

```
.Sample[0].values += [[1028088000000,0]]
```

or if you want to use the Javascript syntax, you could define `def push(x): .[length] = x;`

If you want to replace the last value in the `values` array by another value, say $x, you could (using jq 1.5 or later) write:

```
.Sample[0].values[-1] = $x
```

A more robust (with respect to different jq releases) approach would be:

```
.Sample[0].values |= (.[length-1] = $x)
```

With jq 1.5 or later, if you wanted only to change the negative number to 0, you would write:

```
    .Sample[0].values[-1][-1] = 0
```

Etc.